# Google Cloud Shell: How to interface via command-line terminal?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

I created a very simple python hello_world script on the google cloud shell. I implemented it and ran it within the in-browser google cloud shell and it compiled and outputted correctly.

My question is, what if I want to implement this same hello_world script via a linux server I am on? I currently just downloaded the google SDK and did a 'gcloud init' and set up this hello_world python project onto my linux server by following the google cloud documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads

I am just a little confused on how to access these files on my linux server terminal and run them via linux server terminal. I simply want to run them on here and have the same output as I did on the google cloud shell via the in-browser console.

Comment: Hi @tnet - as is I think this question is a bit too broad.  What have you tried so far?  Maybe if you can narrow the question in on a specific problem you're running into - e.g., "I can SSH in, but I can't open an interpreter", or something like that - then we will be more able to help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, you can simply download the files over to you system.  When you have the shell open, the upper right corner there is the 'more' option and from there you will see the ability to download files directly.  Sorry, if this isn't what you were looking for.

Rick